# Migration to create default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

So 
I want to know whether we can write a new migration just to set default value of a field,which is already created. I know how to write edit the old migration and set its default value. I want to do this because I have done so many migrations and I cant roll back now and edit that file. 
And also, Is there any way to rollback to a particular migration?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
rails g migration add_default_value_to_table
```

then in the migration file

```
def up
    change_column :table_name, :column_name, :string, :default => "abcd"
end

def down
    change_column :table_name, :column_name, :string, :default => nil
end
```

I've used datatype `string` as an example, you can do it for column with any datatype

Comment: if you dont mind can u tell me what this def down does

Comment: def `down` method used when you want to rollback the column to previous state by typing command `rake db:rollback`, its upto you whether you want to define it or not

Answer (score 1):

To rollback a particular migration:-

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20080906120000
```

Then edit the migration and add the default value to that field and run the migration again as

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000
```

Comment: So what happens if i did this in my system and upload it in git and the one who also have the same code pulls the migration file..
if he runs rake db:migrate will this work in his?

Comment: no, he also need to do the same thing if the migration has already been ran

Comment: Yes it will work only when you have not committed that migration before. Otherwise all have to perform the same steps.